# failing to navigate to next screen after applying correct password into showdialog textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating simple note app..where i have set an option of lock note...

a showDialog appears while tapping on LOCKNOTE for password, it should move to next screen on right password...i hve treid with print('success'),, its showing success on right password but not moving to next screen..looks like something related to context,

it work Navigator.of(context).pop() but not working push to next screen

help me to solve this...
Thanks in advance

```
return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemCount: provider.count_notes,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final note = provider.getAllNotes[index];
            return NoteWidget(
              onTap: () {
                if(note.isLocked==true)
                  {
                     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('Enter Password'),
                        content: TextField(
                          controller: txtnotepassword,
                        ),
                        actions: [
                          TextButton(onPressed: (){
                            if(txtnotepassword.text=='123')
                              {
                                print('Success');//shows in log but not moving to nextscreen
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                Navigator.of(context)
                                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                  return EditNoteScreen(
                                    note: note,
                                  );
                                }));
                              }
                            else
                              {
                                showMessage(context,'Wrong Password');

                              }
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }, child: Text('Submit'))],
                      );
                    });

                    return;
                  }

                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return EditNoteScreen(
                    note: note,
                  );
                }));
              },
              note: note,
            );
          }),
    );
```

Comment: Did you try removing the Navigator.of(context).pop() above your push method?

Comment: Yes....but not working

Comment: I figured it out. It's becuase you're using a showDialog() and your dialog is closed before you can call the push method. I'll post a detailed explanation/solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I properly read your code. Doing the `push()` after the `pop()` will never work, because the instant you `pop()`, your AlertDialog will be destroyed, including the function inside it, so your push() method is never called. If you want to try it realtime, try moving your print statement below your pop() method, it will not be printed.

If you want to go to the next page after hitting Submit this is what you should do:

1. Declare a bool flag globally to keep track of whether submit was tapped or not. Eg.

`bool isSubmitted = false;`

2. Inside your `TextButton`'s onPressed function, do this:

```
if (txtnotepassword.text == '123') {
    isSubmitted = true;
} else {
    isSubmitted = false;
    showMessage(context, 'Wrong Password');
}
Navigator.pop(context);
```

3. After your `showDialog`'s ending paranthesis, add a `.then()` callback like this:

```
showDialog(...your dialog UI code here)
  .then((_) {
    if (isSubmitted) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
           return EditNoteScreen(
              note: note,
           );
        }));
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No problem! All the best

Comment: Hi Sir, can u solve this ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76697359/how-to-get-value-from-custom-widget-in-flutter